# Problems with the `loadTexture()` method in the Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've found a few problems with the `loadTexture()` method, which is used to change a sprite's texture. One of the problems that I've found with it is that the spritesheets that are played after loading new textures seem to skip, like so: http://cl.ly/text/123S1n2r1m35

(Here's the code for that example:)

```
// Constants
var GAME_WIDTH = 800;
var GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

var TEXT_X_POS = 260;
var TEXT_Y_POS = 100;

var ALL_FRAMES = null;
var FRAME_RATE = 15;
var LOOP = true;

var SPRITE_X_POS = 300;
var SPRITE_Y_POS = 300;


// New instance of Phaser.Game
var game = new Phaser.Game(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, Phaser.AUTO, "game", { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var sprite;

function preload () {
    game.load.atlas("robot", "sprites/running_bot.png", "sprites/running_bot.json");
    game.load.atlas("sea_creature", "sprites/seacreature.png", "sprites/seacreature.json");
}

function create () {
    game.add.text(TEXT_X_POS, TEXT_Y_POS, "Click to change texture", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});
    sprite = game.add.sprite(SPRITE_X_POS, SPRITE_Y_POS, "robot");
    sprite.animations.add("robot", ALL_FRAMES, FRAME_RATE, LOOP);
    sprite.animations.add("sea_creature", ALL_FRAMES, FRAME_RATE, LOOP);
    sprite.animations.play("robot");
}

function update () {
    game.input.onDown.add(changeTexture, sprite);
}

function changeTexture () {
    sprite.loadTexture("sea_creature");
    sprite.animations.play("sea_creature");
}
```

You'll see that the sea creature's animation seems to skip, and I'm having this same problem with sprites of my own, so this problem is not specific to that particular texture.

Another problem that I've found with it is that when a new texture is loaded onto a sprite, the sizes of the original spritesheet stay on that sprite. For example: http://cl.ly/3F0C2k1G1G2z

(Here's the code for this example:)

```
// Constants
var GAME_WIDTH = 800;
var GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

var CHANGE_TEXTURE_TEXT_X_POS = 260;
var CHANGE_TEXTURE_TEXT_Y_POS = 100;

var ARROW_KEYS_TEXT_X_POS = 260;
var ARROW_KEYS_TEXT_Y_POS = 170;

var SPRITE_X_POS = 300;
var SPRITE_Y_POS = 300;

var WALL_X_POS = 600;
var WALL_Y_POS = 225;

var STOPPED = 0;
var SPRITE_RIGHT_VELOCITY = 150;
var SPRITE_LEFT_VELOCITY = -150;
var SPRITE_UP_VELOCITY = -150;
var SPRITE_DOWN_VELOCITY = 150;


// New instance of Phaser.Game
var game = new Phaser.Game(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, Phaser.AUTO, "game", { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var sprite;
var wall;
var cursorKeys;

function preload () {
    game.load.image("master", "sprites/master.png");
    game.load.image("melon", "sprites/melon.png");
    game.load.image("rectangle", "sprites/Rectangle.png");
}

function create () {
    game.add.text(CHANGE_TEXTURE_TEXT_X_POS, CHANGE_TEXTURE_TEXT_Y_POS, "Click to change texture", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});
    game.add.text(ARROW_KEYS_TEXT_X_POS, ARROW_KEYS_TEXT_Y_POS, "Use arrow keys to move", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});
    sprite = game.add.sprite(SPRITE_X_POS, SPRITE_Y_POS, "master");
    game.physics.arcade.enable(sprite);

    wall = game.add.sprite(WALL_X_POS, WALL_Y_POS, "rectangle");
    game.physics.arcade.enable(wall);
    wall.body.immovable = true;

    cursorKeys = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update () {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, wall);

    game.input.onDown.add(changeTexture, sprite);

    sprite.body.velocity.x = STOPPED;
    sprite.body.velocity.y = STOPPED;

    if (cursorKeys.right.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.x = SPRITE_RIGHT_VELOCITY;
    }
    if (cursorKeys.left.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.x = SPRITE_LEFT_VELOCITY;
    }
    if (cursorKeys.up.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.y = SPRITE_UP_VELOCITY;
    }
    if (cursorKeys.down.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.y = SPRITE_DOWN_VELOCITY;
    }
}

function changeTexture () {
    sprite.loadTexture("melon");
}
```

You'll see here that the first texture collides with the wall just fine, but when the new, smaller texture is loaded onto the sprite, its original sizes are still there. This makes the game look buggy and like the sprite is not actually colliding with the wall. Again, this problem is not specific to this example, as I have am having the same issue with my own sprites.

I really need a way around these problems of this `loadTexture()` method, as they've been causing me a lot of grief with my own project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the issue with the sprite's size:

All that needs to be done is set the sprite's size to the new texture once the new texture is loaded, like so:

```
function changeTexture () {
    sprite.loadTexture("melon");
    sprite.body.setSize(newTexture.width, newTexture.height);
}
```

Concerning the issue with the skipping animations:

What first must be done is specify exactly which frames to use, as opposed to just setting the `frames` parameter as null. Secondly, the particular line where the new animation is added for the new texture must be put in the method where the new texture is loaded, like so:

```
function changeTexture () {
    sprite.loadTexture("sea_creature");
    sprite.animations.add("sea_creature", specificFramesToUse, frameRate, whetherToLoop, whetherToUseANumericIndex);
    sprite.animations.play("sea_creature");
}
```